# JPA Hibernate communication Link failure error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, heroku

I am having a real problem with JPA and Hibernate it sometimes gives a Communication Link failure not sure why it happens every so often not sure why is it a enviroment issue configuration issue can't really get my head around would love some other people input on the issue and hopefully point me in the right direction

Here is the stack trace

```
 21:41:34,726 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:139 - Communications link failure
 2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: The last packet successfully received from the  server was 79,581 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. [n/a]
 2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
  2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]: The last packet successfully received from the server was 79,581 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
 2013-02-21T21:41:34+00:00 app[web.1]:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

POM.xml

```
<properties>
  <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.20</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.27.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- Tiles dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.11</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Junit API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>


<!-- JavaMail API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javamail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javamail</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Java Activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JavaMail extension -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- LOG4J -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- The newrelic-agent.jar dependency. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- The newrelic-api.jar dependency. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- The newrelic-java.zip dependency. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-zip</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
                            <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
                            <version>theVersion</version>
                            <type>zip</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>newrelic</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>/newrelic</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                            <version>7.0.27.1</version>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="dataSource">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
            <property key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property key="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
            <property key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">verify</property>
            <property key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
            <property key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
    </properties>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url"
        value="#{ 'jdbc:mysql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
    <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
    <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: If it happens after 8 hours of idle connection, this could be due to mysql. MySql closes by default closes all idle connections after 8 hours. But I see in your config that you use idle_test_period.. maybe it is not working